# Set buffer rate MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming, progressive-download

My app was recently denied because it is set to stream 60+ mb files from my web server and play them; the MPMoviePlayerController downloaded the entire file in 5-10 minutes while simultaneously playing it. From the testing perspective, the app worked great, but Apple limits audio streaming to 5mb/5min.

How would I go about limiting the buffer rate to only buffer 5mb/5min?

I have no idea which direction to go. I am willing to overhaul as long as the player can still stream the files from my web server.

All replies are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Streaming is limited due to cellular network limits, so the only way to do this is to do this:

Google "HTTP Live Streaming"

Download the tools from Apple's Dev Center and install them

You will need to use Terminal to mediafilesegment the flies

```
mediafilesegmenter /Path\ to\ File/Name.mp3
```

Then upload the .m3u8 files and the segments to your server (same directory)  and stream the m3u8. Problem solved!